# Expiring Headers not detected by Speed Check Services

Tags: magento-1.9, expires-header, pingdom, gtmetrix

I've set this expiring headers rules

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/js "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

but when I go to test it inside pingdom, gtmetrix, pagespeed and so on, I see that they advice me to set the expiring headers. I need to add something else to my code? Or those service don't detect the expiring headers? Or what else to solve this problem? 
I'm Using cloundflare to speed up image loading. Maybe this? But they advice me also to add expiring headers for css, js. But I've yet add all of them.

Comment: ask this on https://serverfault.com